# mongodb rename keys inside an object during aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb aggregation query

```
return this.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectID(locationId) } },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "buildings",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "ownerId",
            as: "areas"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {     
            "location_id": "$_id",
            "locationName": "$locationName", 
            "areas": "$areas"
        }
    }
]).toArray();
```

where the `areas` field is an array of objects

```
[{
  key: value
}]
```

Is it possible to rename this key during the aggregation process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) your areas as following:

```
return this.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectID(locationId) } },
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: "buildings",
           localField: "userId",
           foreignField: "ownerId",
           as: "areas"
         }
    },
    {
        $project: {     "location_id": "$_id",
                        "locationName": "$locationName", 
                        "areas": "$areas"
                  }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$areas"
    },
    {
        $group: {   "_id": {"location_id": "$_id", "locationName": "$locationName"}, 
                    "areas": {$push: {new_key: "$areas.key"}} //<== renaming 'key' to 'new_key'
                }
    },
    {
        $project: {     "_id": 0,
                        "location_id": "$_id.location_id",
                        "locationName": "$_id.locationName", 
                        "areas": "$areas"
                  }
    }
]).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, though maybe not as easily as you might expect.

First you need to use `$unwind` to get a document per area. Than `$group` the documents with the same location (thus same `_id`) back together.

The `$group` actually also does a projection. You can use `$first` in `$group` to select fields that ware not unwinded.

*You haven't told the properties of an area object. In the example I assume it has a `coords` and `shape` property.*

```
return this.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectID(locationId) } },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "buildings",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "ownerId",
            as: "areas"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$areas"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "location_id": { $first: "$_id" },
            "locationName": { $first: "$locationName" },
            "areas": {
                $push: {
                    "latitude": "$coords.lat",
                    "longitude": "$coords.lon",
                    "shape": "$shape"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).toArray();
```

*Note that you do end up with an additional `_id` field (which may be ignored), because `$group` requires an `_id`.*